# Rails: Why does failing validate_uniqeness still allow save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

-- Question rewritten based on further testing --

So, my app has_many Folders which belong_to Collections.
Folders are nested, they can also belong_to another Folder.

I want to validate uniqueness of the folder names within each collection. When I create folders at the top level this works, but when I create it in lower levels it does not work. Here are the models:

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  # CALLBACKS
  before_create :associate_collection

  # RELATIONSHIPS
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Folder'
  has_many :subfolders, :class_name => 'Folder', :foreign_key => :parent_id

  # VALIDATIONS
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :collection_id

  private

  def associate_collection
    if self.collection.nil?
    self.collection = self.parent.collection
    end
  end
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base

  # RELATIONSHIPS
  has_one :root_folder, :class_name => 'Folder', :conditions => { :parent_id => nil }
  has_many :folders

  # CALLBACKS
  after_create :setup_root_folder

  private

  def setup_root_folder
    self.create_root_folder(:name=>'Collection Root')
    self.save!
  end

end
```

Here's an abridged example of what happens in the console:

```
c = Collection.new(:name=>'ExampleCollection')
#<Collection id: 1>

root = c.root_folder
#<Folder id: 1, collection_id: 1>

f1 = root.subfolders.create(:name=>'Test')
#<Folder id: 2 collection_id: 1> 

f1.valid?
# TRUE

f2 = root.subfolders.create(:name=>'Test')
#<Folder id: 3 collection_id: 1>

f2.valid?
# FALSE

f1.valid?
# FALSE
```

So, while the collection is being associated with a subfolder correctly, its not triggering the validations correctly until after it's saved.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh.

My `associate_collection` callback needs to happen `before_validation`, not `before_create`.

Fixed. Thanks for looking guys!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to explain it is that the validation is being called before the collection_id is assigned, due to the syntax you are using. Maybe try

```
Folder.create(:collection => @collection, :name => 'example')
```

and see if it changes anything.

Comment: That's not true. Calling `@collection.folders.create` calls `Folder.create` within the scope of `@collection`.

Comment: Interesting. Would adding `:inverse_of => :collection` to the `has_many` help here?

Comment: That's odd because on save the `collection_id` is set correctly. And, even more strange IMO, once the second record is created BOTH records return false if you call `valid?` on them. So, do you know WHY creating records through the association doesn't apply the scope?

Comment: Weird. Sorry, I've never seen that used before. Maybe the `collection_id` is being set after the validation, since its being called that way? Try my suggestion and see if the validation fires properly.

Comment: What happens if you call `@collection.folders(true).create(:name=>'example')` instead the second time?

Comment: @nathan.f77 - your suggestion works in all cases, so I can do that. I found that my original approach does work as long as I call it from all the way up the chain -- ie folders are nested, so if I call `collection.folders.first.folders.create()` etc. it works, but if I have a folder in an instance variable or something and try to use it it doesn't work. Anyway, I think that means its a callback issue, so I'll have to investigate further.